# How do I force broken wires with intrinsic typecast (between incompatible pointers/references) in LabVIEW?

Tags: dll, typedef, labview

I like using free software libraries in C with the Call Library Function Node, I'm currently programming the LibXML2 interface.  With it, I have DLL pointers to docs, nodes, elements, etcetera, defined as Magic cookies to locations in the DLL memory space.

When I create strict typedefs for nodes and docs, LabView allows me to wire a doc magic cookie to a node magic cookie (or pointer, and visa-versa) and only indicates an intrinsic cast. Is there a way to define a reference or unsigned 32 typedef that yield a broken wire instead of allowing it with the red dot of intrinsic casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's a bit weird, but the technique has been used for a long time (LV3.0 at least) and isn't going anywhere.

Let's say you want to create a Node magic cookie type.

1. Create an enum typedef and 1 one element in the enum. Make the text of the element be "Node". Save the enum as "Node Enum.ctl"
2. Make a new typedef. Drop a datalog refnum on the front panel and put Node Enum.ctl inside of it. Save this as "Node Reference.ctl". Give this .ctl a good icon for your type.
3. Now whenever you have an int32 that you return from your Call Library Node, use the Type Cast primitive to cast that int32 as a "Node Reference.ctl". (Alternatively, you can make the type of the Call Library Node terminals be "Adapt To Type" and then wire in one of these ctls to define the type.)

Now build a second one of these, but everywhere that I wrote "Node", substitute "Doc".

If you do this, a wire of type "Node Reference.ctl" will not coerce to a wire of type "Doc Reference.ctl". Both will behave as refnum wires, and you have a strong type for your references.

Comment: It simply means that one has to create wrapper around dll calls. But if one will forget to put input/output to dll call as the specific enum, but will leave there integer control/indicator - then it will be possible to connect there whatever suits to integer data type.

Comment: I agree on the wrapper to DLL calls - that was the intension all along.  I want to provide the LabVIEW user the functions of this bestest, most-maintained-ist XML libraries available, all without any required knowledge of C or DLLs, only of LabVIEW.

Comment: It's weird, the display is wrong but probing it shows the correct values.

Comment: What display? It’s a refnum. There shouldn’t be a display unless you write a custom XControl.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible due to same "main" type of your typedef and Call Library Function Node inputs. Typedef will work in case of incompatible enums, rings or clusters - when LabVIEW will not know how to convert or match datatypes.

In your case - you could use VI Analyzer tests which search for coertion dots ([Block Diagram Tests (VI Analyzer Toolkit)](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvvianalyzerhelp/block_diagram_tests/)). Or, if it is possible - create subVI wrappers around your dll calls with typedef clusters with U32 as inputs/outputs of the VI - separate for different types of nodes. Then, when you'll call those subVIs in higher-level API you will be able to connect just the proper input types between each other. But of course, it depends how that dll is made.

The other option - which does not directly answers your question - is to use LabVIEW toolkits for XML parsing, which are available on LabVIEW Tools Network and most of them are free (you could download them also using VI Package Manager).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the coercion dots. We have the LV Toolkits XML stuff, it's half what LibXML2 is. LibXML2 is working very well, actually, I do use quite a bit of CLFN with DSSetHandleSize() to resize arrays for large results.